# whether it is necessary to update the partitions if the schema remains the same, but new data is added

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena, amazon-cloudtrail

I'd like to monitor/analyze CloudTrail log files which are stored at S3 bucket.
So, I read AWS docs about how CloudTrail and Athena works, and for optimization of Athena queries I decided to create some partitions.

Here is example of structure of data at S3:

`s3://<s3 bucket name>/AWSLogs/<account id>/CloudTrail/<region>/<year>/<month>/<day>/CloudTrail-log-file.json.gz`.

So, should **`LOCATION`** be equal to `s3://<s3 bucket name>/AWSLogs/<account id>/CloudTrail/` ?

And partitions are: `region`, `year`, `month`, `day`?

**And the main question is**: whether it is necessary to update the partitions if the schema remains the same, but new data is added (for example new `dir` with year/month/day)? Or if schema will be the same I should define partitions only once?

If partitions have to be updated when new `dir` like year/month/day is added, which way is the best for this purpose (use custom Lambda trigger on S3 with only Athena API, OR use/configure Glue Crawler)?

Thanks a lot for any information about this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you use partition projection, there's no need to update them. Here are the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection.html